# Hyperledger Fabric peer instantiate chaincode error

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I am getting this error while trying to instantiate chaincode on peer1 of org1.

NodeJS console error :

> Failed to send Proposal and receive all good ProposalResponse Failed
>   to instantiate. cause:Failed to send Proposal and receive all good
>   ProposalResponse (node:25005) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error:
>   Failed to instantiate. cause:Failed to send Proposal and receive all
>   good ProposalResponse

Blockchain console error :

> ERRO 692 [[e9585782 PUT_STATE ERROR]]No ledger context for
>   %!!(MISSING)s(MISSING). Sending %!!(MISSING)s(MISSING) ERRO 6a2
>   [bloqchannel][e9585782] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" ,
>   error: timeout expired while executing transaction

I am using Hyperledger Fabric 1.1 and Hyperledger fabric node SDK.
The nodeJS version is 8.11.2.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: The code is of balance transfer but little modified according to my use case.

Comment: Can you specify what steps did you follow?Any code ?

Comment: @Rupsingh the issue is resolved. thanks.